# Why does this algorithm work for reverse bit

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

Hey guys Im confused on this code in terms of what the variables n and b are used for. I know what each line of code is doing I just dont understand the significant of it in how does it do bit reverse. If someone could help understand each line that would be great. I have commented on some lines of the code on what I think its doing

```
        int r = 0;//initalizing r though it doesn't matter what value we use 
        while (b)//don't understand the meaning here
        {
            r <<= 1; //I know this means left shift one or multiply by 2
            r |= (n & 1);//I believe this line says AND the number with 1
            n >>= 1;//divide by 2
            b >>= 1;//divide by 2
        }
        return r;
```

Comment: It does not work! It invokes undefined behaviour **and** relies on implementation defined behaviour. Also this is no "explain my code" site. Do you have a **specific** problem?

Comment: `while(b)` -> `while(b!=0)`, and `r|=(n&1)`: add the lowest bit of `n` to `r`, i.o.w. set the lowest bit of `r` to the lowest bit of `n` (works only because the lowest bit of `r` is initially 0). What's `b`?

Comment: What are `b` and `n`?

Comment: @MikeCAT that;s what I want to know

Comment: @KarstenKoop because the lowest bit of r is initally 0 does this mean that this reverse bit code wont work for all cases. Maybe thats why Olaf said this code doesn't work

Comment: No, it's just that `r|=(n&1)` only sets the lowest bit of `r` to the lowest bit of `n` if the lowest bit of `r` is currently 0, because of the bitwise or. But the initializing and bitwise shift left make sure that it is indeed 0.

Comment: Don't think "divide" and "multiply" when you're trying to understand bitwise operations. Stick to "shift right" and "shift left" and forget that the bits represent a number at all. Work through an example by hand on paper and you'll see how it works (keep it short, two or three bits should be enough to get the idea).

Comment: @I_love_coding_93: the variables `b` and `n` come from somewhere. What are they?

Comment: `while (b)` --> Scroll all bits of `b` until there is at least one bit set to `1` into `b`.

Comment: `n` contains the bits to be reversed. `b` decides how many bits of `n` to put reversed into the result, `r`. Why `b` isn't a number but a bitmask is impossible to guess.

Comment: @LPs The thing I don't get is that when i run this it says that r n and b are not declared in the scope but it's all within the same function and just because its not declared in a while loop should not make a difference

Comment: I'm not getting you: first of all you are compiling the code: you do not run it.  2nd You must have `n` and `b` variables: I guess that are parameters passed by value to the function that implement the posted code.

Comment: @LPs ignore that part that was dumb of me sorry but I tried plugging in n for 170 and b for 5 and when I compiled the program I got r to be 2 so does that mean the logic in the program is wrong?

Comment: No, it works. In your case `n=0xAA` so the while loops 3 times due to the succession of b values: Loop1-->`b=0x05` and `r=0x00` - Loop2 --> `b=0x02` and `r=0x01` - Loop3 --> `b=0x01` and `r=0x02`

Comment: @Lps you said earlier that r=0x04 if n=0xAA and b=0x05. Was that a typo?

Comment: @Yes, sorry. My error. I cancel the comment.

Comment: @LPs my last question is I dont understand the significance of right and left shifting in this case

Comment: Take a look at my answer, I hope it helps

Comment: @Lps I still don't get why shifting r left by 1 and shifting n and b right by 1 helps

Comment: I tried to explain something better in my answer.

Comment: @LPs How is 2 the reverse bit of 170 when b=5. 170 is expressed as 0b10101010 but 2 is expressed as 0b10. Shouldn't bit reverse look like this : 0010 0000 => 0000 0100. In that case you see how the bits have switched but in the above case it doesn't appear to look like that?

Comment: As already explained: it b that define how menay loops will be performed. So if you want a complete reverse you will set b to 0xFF, for example or 0x80 as you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post it only to show how it works. Hope it helps:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void print8Bits( char *var_name, uint8_t value )
{
    uint8_t mask = 0x80;

    printf("%s = 0b", var_name);

    while (mask)
    {
        printf("%c", (value & mask) ? '1':'0');

        mask >>= 1;
    }

    printf(" - %02X\n", value);
}

int main(void)
{
    uint8_t b=5;
    uint8_t n=0xAA;
    uint8_t r = 0;//initalizing r though it doesn't matter what value we use+

    while (b)//don't understand the meaning here
    {
        r <<= 1; //I know this means left shift one or multiply by 2
        r |= (n & 1);//I believe this line says AND the number with 1
        n >>= 1;//divide by 2
        b >>= 1;//divide by 2

        print8Bits("r", r);
        print8Bits("n", n);
        print8Bits("b", b);

        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
r = 0b00000000 - 00
n = 0b01010101 - 55
b = 0b00000010 - 02

r = 0b00000001 - 01
n = 0b00101010 - 2A
b = 0b00000001 - 01

r = 0b00000010 - 02
n = 0b00010101 - 15
b = 0b00000000 - 00
```

As you can see:

- as far as `b` has a value `!= 0` the while continue looping.
- each loop the value of `bit 1` of n is stored into `bit 1` of `n` and then left shifted.
- each loop value of `n` is right shifted to prepare a new bit into `bit 1` position.